# What effect does the left/right hand have on my weapon?

Tags: elden-ring

So, I started as the Warrior class in Elden Ring, which starts with 2 scimitars and a shield. Attacking with L1 wields both swords, attacking with R1 and R2 wields 1 sword, and attacking with L2 wields one sword (I believe) with the special ability.

Right now, I primarily wield both swords, and attack with the L1 combo. But my swords are at +2 and +4, and I don't know which hand I should wield which weapon with, especially if I want to switch to my shield?

Comment: I've already suggested an edit, but just in case if you misremembered spelling, it's [wield](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wield) not weild.

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to have mostly reinforced weapon on your right hand, and shield on your left hand.

It's because enchantment sorceries/incantations only enchants your right-hand weapon (for example, [Scholar's Armament](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Scholar%27s+Armament) and [Electrify Armament](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Electrify+Armament)), while shield enchantment sorceries/incantations only enchants your left-hand shield (for example, [Scholar's Shield](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Scholar%27s+Shield) and [Immutable Shield](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Immutable+Shield)).

<s>Even if you don't plan on using sorceries/incantations, weapon enchanting items, such as [Fire Grease](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Fire+Grease), can only enchant your right-hand weapon, despite it's not written in text. This is because you'll use the item with your left hand.</s>
Information from @BunnyMerz:

> You can always dual-wield your left hand weapon to apply buffs and then un-dual-wield to buff the right hand weapon. Can't confirm it still works, but that is an old trick that should work.

I've tested if it's still doable in Elden Ring, and found out that we're still able to do it.

Having two weapons from same category (with exception: Katanas on the right hand, Wakizashi(categorized as dagger) on your left hand can activate power stance) will make you use its powerstance(dual-wield).
As you noticed, your movement set will change if powerstance is activated. R1 and R2 and L2 doesn't change, but L1 changes - use two weapons at the same time, resulting overall higher damage.
And if your weapons has any status effect, such as [hemorrhage](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Hemorrhage), [frostbite](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Frostbite) etc., will proc both of status effect if both weapons hit your enemies.
L2 will just act as right-hand weapon's skill.

By the way, powerstancing is not causing to let you use right-hand weapon's skill. More like, your shield is preventing your right-hand weapon's skill. If your shield has a skill, such as parry, shield bash, will make L2 to use shield's skill over right-hand weapon's skill. Some shields that doesn't have skills will let you use your right-hand weapon's skill. Also, you can use [No Skill Ash of War](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Ash+of+War:+No+Skill) to make your shields to have no skill.

Comment: What about the weapon skill? I.e. the L2 attack? When k have 2 swords I can use it without holding the weapon 2-handed

Comment: @Ben Yeah I've forgot mentioning that, I've edited to include it in my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: You can always dual-wield your left hand weapon to apply buffs and then un-dual-wield to buff the right hand weapon. Can't confirm it still works, but that is an old trick that should work.

Comment: @BunnyMerz Oh, I didn't know that you could do that. I'll test it later if it's still doable. Do you mind if I merge your comment to my answer afterwards?

Comment: I don't mind, always good practice to do so.